# How to add filters to a c++ getline() function?

Tags: c++, windows, getline

I am trying to parse through a gcode and I want to extract only the x & y coordinates of G1 from each line

GCODE EXAMPLE

> `G1 X123.456 Y125.425 Z34.321`

I tried the basic `getline()` function but it prints the whole line, don't understand how to add filters to the `getline()` to just extract only x & y numerical values and only for lines with G1 on start.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout; using std::cerr;
using std::endl; using std::string;
using std::ifstream; using std::vector;

int main()
{
    string filename("test1.gcode");
    vector<string> lines;
    string line;

    ifstream input_file(filename);
    if (!input_file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '"
             << filename << "'" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (getline(input_file, line)){
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    for (const auto &i : lines)
        cout << i << endl;

    input_file.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Minor point: you don't need to call `input_file.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Comment: The way to filter a file is to read everything and then ignore the bits you don't care about

Comment: You can't add filters to `getline()`; its job is to read a line. Full stop. After reading the line you can do whatever you need to with the result. Like search for `'X'` and then for `'Y'`.

Comment: @PeteBecker can you show how to search for X & Y after that?

Comment: @Mohit -- begin by reading the documentation for [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add filters to `getline()`. It will always return the complete next line in the input.

What you can do is parse this line yourself, and extract the values that you need.
This is can be done in multiple ways. One of them is demonstrated below.

I used [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to get an offset for the character 'X'/'Y' marking the x/y coordinates.
Then I used [`std::atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) to convert the relevant part of the line to a `double` value.
I also used `std::string::find` to check whether the line starts with the required prefix for this command.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string line = "G1 X123.456 Y125.425 Z34.321";

    if (line.find("G1") == 0)
    {
        size_t xpos = line.find('X');
        if (xpos == std::string::npos) { /* handle error */ }
        double x = std::atof(line.data() + xpos + 1); // skip over the 'X'

        size_t ypos = line.find('Y');
        if (ypos == std::string::npos) { /* handle error */ }
        double y = std::atof(line.data() + ypos + 1); // skip over the 'Y'

        std::cout << "X: " << x << ", Y: " << y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
X: 123.456, Y: 125.425
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle structured data is... with a struct.

```
struct line_item {
    int g;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, line_item& item) {   
    line_item temp; 
    item = {};
    in >> 'G' >> temp.g >> 'X' >> temp.x >> 'Y' >> temp.y >> 'Z' >> temp.z;
    if (in) 
        item = temp;
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const line_item& item) { 
    return out << 'G' << item.g << " X" << item.x << " Y" << item.y << " Z" << item.z;
}
```

Normally one can't `istream >> 'G'`, so I have a helper for that.

```
//helper function for "reading in" character literals
template<class e, class t>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e& char_literal) {
    e buffer;  //get buffer
    in >> buffer; //read data
    if (buffer != char_literal) //if it failed
            in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit); //set the state
    return in;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6af1f3c881cc9e6e

Then you read in the items using the normal `istream>>line_item`, and from there, you have structured data that you can do whatever you want with, such as creating a secondary struct that only stores the items you care about.